# uitableview with paging must display only 10 cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my app I have `UITableView` as a `subview` of `UIScrollView` with many number of `cells` . Now I want to do this paging firstly `UITableView` must contain `10 cells`. I'm new to the concept paging.
I'm not getting any idea how to start this I referred some tutorials but of no use.

Can any one help me how to start paging for `UITableView`.

This is how am creating `UITableView` and having some delegate methods

```
              self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,150,730, [listofItems count]*160) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
                self.tableView.delegate=self;
                self.tableView.dataSource=self;
                self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
                self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                [testscroll addSubview:self.tableView];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Initially pass only 10 elements to the `array`.

2) Consider two `buttons` like next & previous, On that `button click` remove older elements from `array`.

3) Add newer 10 elements to the `array`.

4) `reload table data`.

Consider following demo example :

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    //Remove the older objects
   [listofItems removeAllObjects];
   //Add your new 10 objects to the array
   [listofItems addObjects:@"obj1", @"obj2", @"obj3", @"obj4", @"obj5", @"obj6", @"obj7", @"obj8", @"obj9" , @"obj10", nil];
   //Reload the table
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: am loading the data in cells dynamically from service.how can i display onlyy ten cells

Comment: Means you stored all elements in one array while parsing correct?

Comment: Take temp array & add 10 elements each time from main array to temp array each time & passed the temp array to the table.

Comment: in my tableview am passing data using conditions how can i do that for every array

Comment: Passed the temp array when condition satisfies instead of the array which you passed yet.

Comment: solved but some problem.i added this tableview to scrollview .in tableviewcell am having a button when on click  it displays a label on scrollview .now adding this step  [self.tableView reloadData]; does not call cellforrow method

Comment: in .h implement UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate delegates.

Comment: i added those delegates.first time when i'm getting tableview displayed and paging also works fine.but, am having a button when on click it displays a label on scrollview after this cell forrow at index path not called